# How do I calculate integer and half integer spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

How do I calculate integer and half integer spin, and how do I use the calculations?

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit to explain what calculations you're trying to do.